# Building model that loops through several origin/destination points to create several different trip routes in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, network, route

I have a Network Dataset ready to go for the streets of New York City, and from that I'd like to map out a table of individual taxi cap trips. From what I've been told, I should be using ModelBuilder to loop through each row of the taxi data, use that to parse out points for each individual trips pickup origin and drop-off destination, and use those points to create individual routes for each trip so that I ultimately have a shapefile containing several lines (one for each trip) following the street network. I am trying my best to figure out how to get this to work, but it has been incredibly confusing.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve such a task using the ModelBuilder, you can simply do the following [(Tutorial Link)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-6-creating-a-model-for-route-analysis.htm):

1. Create [Network dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm).
2. Create New Model.
3. Insert [(Make Route Layer)](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/network-analyst/make-route-layer.htm) into the model and add your network dataset to it.
4. Insert ([Add locations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/add-locations.htm)) into the model and add your taxi points to it.
5. Connect the output Route of the (Make route layer) to the (Add locations).
6. Add the tool ([Solve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/solve.htm)) and connect the (Add location) output to it.
7. The final route layer, right click and add to display.

You can change the parameters and inputs according to your task requirements and data.